# Picketlink on JBoss sends LogoutRequest to incorrect endpoint

Tags: security, jboss, idp, picketlink

I'm trying to secure an application using picketlink. I'm using JBoss 6.4.18.

The SSO operation works without any issues. The problem is with the SLO, basically, picketlink sends the LogoutRequest assertion to the wrong endpoint. The IdP metadata inside my war has these endpoints:

```
<md:ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/soap" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/slo" ResponseLocation="https://myidp.com/saml2/slo_return"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/slo" ResponseLocation="https://myidp.com/saml2/slo_return"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/soap"/>
<md:ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/rni" ResponseLocation="https://myidp.com/saml2/rni_return"/>
<md:ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/rni" ResponseLocation="https://myidp.com/saml2/rni_return"/>
<md:ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/soap"/>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/sso"/>
<md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/sso"/>
<md:NameIDMappingService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://myidp.com/saml2/soap"/>
```

LogoutRequest assertion looks good to me, but, picketlink sends it to the /sso endpoint instead of using /slo (as indicated by the metadata). When the idp receives that LogoutRequest it doesn't even redirect the browser back to the SP application.

The assertion actually has the correct destination, but as I said, the browser sends to the /sso endpoint.

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                 Destination="https://myidp.com/saml2/sso"
```

Is this a bug in picketlink? 
I must say that I've configured it using other IdP servers where the endpoint is the same for both types of assertions, in such cases, the SLO worked perfectly.

I'd appreciate your help on this one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't fix this by configuration. One would expect picketlink to send the SLO assertions to the endpoint declared in the metadata file, but as I described in the question above it doesn't.

By checking the plugin code I saw that it can read a request parameter to decide what endpoint send the Logout Request assertion to.

So, when the SP requests a GLO I add another request parameter as follows:

```
/?GLO=true&picketlink.desired.idp="+encodedSLOEndpointURL
```

picketlink reads that parameter (picketlink.desired.idp) and sends the assertion to that endpoint on the IdP side.

P.S. I hope this is the last time I have to deal with such an old library like picketlink.